# Submersible pump won't continue to run

Tags: pump, sump-pump

Last summer I put a Wayne [VIP50](https://www.waynepumps.com/product/vip50/) submersible pump under my crawlspace. This winter there's about 6" of water in there and I checked out the pump. Since the discharge hose had a kink, the water couldn't come out. The pump was running the whole time too, don't know how long it was running. But after the kink is fixed, water comes out in spurs. The pump also does that, runs for 3 seconds, stops, runs again, stops, then runs again. So, was the pump damaged since the hose was kinked for however long and it was left running?

Answer (score 2):

Might have overheated - if so it should get better when it has a chance to cool down. You could try turning it off for an hour os so.

Might be damaged in some other way, in which case it probably won't improve. For non-temporary use, pipe beats hose as it won't kink while you are not looking at it.

Intake might be clogged, too - it may be pumping out what filters in, running out of water to pump, stopping, and repeating that cycle. Check and clean the intake area.